# Annoying problem with Ubuntu moving application to different workspace

Tags: workspaces, workspace-switcher

VERSION="22.04.1 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)"

I keep Thunderbird on workspace #1.
When I'm on workspace #2, and click on the docked icon, I am switched to WS#1.  I then interact with Thunderbird, and maybe within ten seconds, Thunderbird is moved to a different workspace.  This seems to happen about 50% of the time with this workflow.

Comment: What do you mean "to a different workspace"? How do you see/experience that Thunderbird is moved? To what workspace is Thunderbird removed? Workspaces are dynamically created and deleted, but Workspace 1 will always there so I would expect Thunderbird remains there.

Comment: I usually have four workspaces open.  One for CAD, one for VSCode, one for email/social.  Then that fourth one is usually empty.  Thunderbird usually goes from WS1 to workspace #2.  It just happened again.  I was on WS2, and clicked on the TB docker icon that brought me to WS1.  It's a habit.  I then worked on a web browser for five or so minutes.  Then, I clicked on TB bar to bring it to the front.  About 1 second later, it shot off to WS#2.